# ZkSync Sepolia support?

Tags: gnosis-safe, testnets, safe-core, sepolia, zksync

we are currently developing a solution to tokenize billions of dollar of real world asset on ZkSync Era and we need add support for multi-signature scheme. I can see [here](https://docs.safe.global/api-supported-networks) that there is support for mainnet though, but we need support for the Sepolia testnet.

Does Gnosis Safe support ZkSync Sepolia testnet already ? Or do you plan to add support to it soon ?

Answer (score 0):

As of now we do not plan to add support to testnets to Safe Transaction Service as it represents a significant amount of resources on our side to maintain. Safe contracts (v1.3.0) are deployed on these networks though, so you can test your implementation there before moving to mainnet and use all the capabilities of the transaction service.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis